# Templated bubblesort

Tags: c++, templates

I want to make just a simple bubble sort which will work with any container: list, vector...

```
template<typename T>
void simpleSort(T& container){
    for(typename T::iterator iterA = container.begin(); iterA != container.end(); ++iterA){
        for(typename T::iterator iterB = iterB; iterB != container.end(); ++iterB){
            if(*iterA > *iterB){
                typename T::value_type temp{*iterA};
                *iterA = *iterB;
                *iterB = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    vector<int> a = {10, 4, 66, 2, 444};
    simpleSort(a);
    for_each(a.begin(),a.end(), [](int i) {cout << i << endl;});
}
```

//Getting segmentation fault here

Comment: Typically, for a generic algorithm, you would accept iterators to the range of elements instead of a reference to the container.

Comment: By the way, your implementation won't work for plain arrays. You probably want to get iterator types via `decltype(std::begin(container))`.

Comment: Did you mean for `typename T::iterator iterB = iterB` to be `typename T::iterator iterB = iterA`? You just assigned `iterB` to itself. If so, I would vote to close this for being a typo.

Comment: Try compiling with full warnings `warning: variable 'iterB' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization`. You could also replace the innermost code with `std::swap` or `std::iter_swap`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, yeap that worked, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line:

```
for(typename T::iterator iterB = iterB; iterB != container.end(); ++iterB){
```

You assign the un-initialized iterB to iterB instead of the value iterA.

Comment: Questions that are the result of a simple typo should be closed rather than answered. [*"Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I am blind, thx.

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem; and should be a little more efficient.

```
template<typename Type>
void simpleSort( Type& container ) {
    typename Type::iterator iterA = container.begin();
    typename Type::iterator iterB;
    for ( ; iterA != container.end(); ++iterA ) {
        for ( iterB = iterA; iterB != container.end(); ++iterB ) {
            if ( *iterA > *iterB ) {
                /*typename Type::value_type temp { *iterA };
                *iterA = *iterB;
                *iterB = temp;*/
                std::iter_swap( iterA, iterB );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As SoronelHaetir mentioned in his answer; you were initializing `iterB` to itself that was already uninitialized. This can lead to UB and segmentation fault by accessing invalid iterator indexes. Also what makes the above here slightly more efficient is that I removed the declaration of `iterA` from the first for loop and initialized it only once instead of checking it every time in the for loop.